Is a Turing Machine required to generate the digits of pi?
$\pi$ belongs to the class of computable numbers, so we can of course compute it to arbitrary precision using a Turing Machine. There also exists an unbounded spigot algorithm which will produce all digits of $\pi$ in the limit of its non-terminating execution. An algorithm of either form constitutes a representation of $\pi$. I am wondering, which, if any, weaker computational models are sufficient to represent $\pi$.
For instance, we might adapt the definition of a finite-state transducer (FST) to obtain a machine that "streams" the base-$b$ representation of a real number in the interval [0,1] (I apologize in advance if I am reinventing a standard definition; FSTs represent relations on strings and Büchi automata represent sets of strings, where as I am interested in representing a single string (number)).
A base-$b$ real number in the interval $[0,1]$ can be represented by an infinite sequence of base-$b$ digits $w = w_1, w_2, \ldots$ Denote by $\langle\!\langle w\rangle\!\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} w_i b^{-i}$ the number represented by $w$.
A finite-state numeral machine (FNM) is a tuple $M = \langle Q, q_0, \delta, b,
\sigma\rangle$, where $Q$ is a finite set of states, $q_0 \in Q$ is the initial
state, $\delta : Q\to Q$ is the transition function, $b$ is the base, and
$\sigma : Q\to\{\epsilon,0,1,2,...,b-1\}$ is the output function. The machine
$M$ visits a sequence of states $q = q_0, q_1, q_2, \ldots$, where $q_{i+1} =
\delta(q_i)$ for $i > 0$. Let $w$ be the sequence of base-$b$ digits obtained
by applying $\sigma$ to the sequence of states visited by $M$ (dropping any
$\epsilon$). Then $M$ represent the number $\langle\!\langle w \rangle\!\rangle$.
It seems unlikely that an FNM is sufficient to represent $\pi$, but I have not tried to prove this. Because the machine is deterministic and the states finite, there will eventually be a cycle. $\pi$ is of course free of such cycles. There are of course many models of computation of varying expressive power. For instance, we might define a model as above that is analogous to a pushdown automaton.
A pushdown numeral machine (PNM) is a tuple $M = \langle Q, q_0, \Gamma, z_0, \delta, b, \sigma\rangle$, where $Q$ is a finite set of states, $q_0 \in Q$ is the initial state, $\Gamma$ is a finite set of stack symbols, $z_0 \in \Gamma$ is the initial stack symbol, $\delta : Q\times\Gamma\to Q\times\Gamma^*$ is the transition function, $b$ is the base, and $\sigma : Q\to\{\epsilon,0,1,2,...,b-1\}$ is the output function. A stack configuration is any element of $\Gamma^*$. An element $z\in\Gamma$ is at the top of a stack configuration $Z$ if $z$ is the last element of $Z$. Hence, pushing sequence of stack symbols $\alpha$ onto a stack configuration $Z$ results in the stack configuration $Z\alpha$ and popping a symbol $z$ from the stack configuration $Zz$ results in the stack configuration $Z$.
The PNM $M$ visits a sequence of states $q = q_0, q_1, q_2, \ldots$ and a sequence of stack configurations $Z = Z_0, Z_1, Z_2, \ldots$, with $Z_0 = z_0$. In particular, if $Z_i = Z_i'z_i$ and $(q, \alpha) = \delta(q_i, z_i)$, then $q_{i+1} = q$ and $Z_{i+1} = Z_i'\alpha$. I.e., the transition function pops $z_i$ from the stack configuration $Z_i$, pushes $\alpha$ onto the stack configuration $Z_i'$, and updates the state as a function of the popped symbol and the current state. Let $w$ be the sequence of base-$b$ digits obtained by applying $\sigma$ to the sequence of states visited by $M$ (dropping any $\epsilon$); then $M$ represents the number $\langle\!\langle w \rangle\!\rangle$.
Question: FNMs are insufficient for representing $\pi$. Turing Machines are sufficient. Is there some model that is sufficient, yet weaker than a Turing Machine (for instance, a PNM)?

You are asking several questions at once. This is generally not a good idea. As to the maths, surely your FNMs produce sequences of digits that are eventually periodic and hence are rational.

@RobArthan thank you for your advice. I have removed ambiguity about which question I’d like answered. And yes, I see now the correspondence between FNMs and rational numbers, thanks.

Just adding that I am unable to come up with a PNM that produces an irrational number, so it may well be that FNM and PNM are equivalently expressive. It's not obvious to me why that is the case though. Another possible model would be to adapt Queue Automata. As decision procedures for finite strings, these automata are equivalent to Turing Machines. So it may well be that they can compute all computable numbers in the spigot setting. They are powerful enough to produce, e.g., the irrational number corresponding to 01011011101111...

I suspect the pumping lemma will also explain why your PNMs can only produce rational numbers.

@RobArthan I had the same thought, but I’m not sure how to adapt it to this setting where I have a machine representing a single infinite string rather than a set of finite strings.
